# Error Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer Existe en dos lugares a la vez

Tags: .net

A la hora de compilar el código me produce el siguient error:

> The type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' exists in both
>   'c:\Users\cargomme\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\71efd4ac\4caf1d86\assembly\dl3\7e8ab3ae\00f6cd85_5d35cc01\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL'
>   and
>   'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL'

Ya intenté:

1)Recompilar la solución.
2)Borrar los archivos temporales de .net
3)Borrar la carpeta de appdata.
4)comentar

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
```

y ninguna funcionó, ayuda porfa.

Comment: Intenta borrando las carpetas bin y obj de tu proyecto, también cierra los procesos de visual studio completamente antes de borrar. Y vuelve a compilar.

Comment: ahora me sale otro error :(

Error No se pudo cargar el tipo 'AdministracionWEB.MvcApplication'. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\eda\AdministracionWEB\AdministracionWeb

Comment: Borre solo las dll de Bin y funcionó, mil Gracias.

Comment: Por qué le pediste solucionado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucioné el problema Borrando la carpeta debug de Obj y borrando las 2 dll de reportviewer de la carpeta bin del proyecto.